# Shell Script - Unix

Tags: regex, shell, unix

```
grep "<ValidateXYZResponse" filename.log* | grep -v "<ResponseCode>000<ResponseCode>"
```

Above command works fine in UNIX where grep -v excludes the records having response code "000"

However, along with "000", I need to exclude the following response codes too: "404", "410", "403", "406"

I am new to unix shell script.

If anyone knows how to do it, please help. Appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: Read some basic documentation on regex.  There is something called alternation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about unwillingness to RTFM.

Comment: @devnull - I sure will learn the basics. Asked question here because I have to send some reports quickly and this is the first time I am using unix shell script.

Comment: It would have taken you much less than the time in which you received the first answer only if you were willing to RTFM.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do  `(foo|bar|blah)` to implement `OR` in regex. Like:

```
grep ...|grep -v '<...>\(000\|40[346]\|410\)<...>'
```

or

```
grep ...|grep -vE '<...>(000|40[346]|410)<...>'
```

detailed explanation about regex-alternation:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "<ValidateXYZResponse" filename.log* | grep -Pv "<ResponseCode>(?:000|40[346]|410)<ResponseCode>"
```

- The `(?:000|40[346]|410)` non-capturing group in the middle gives a list of codes to exclude
- `|` is the alternation (OR) operator
- `[346]` means one character that is either `3`, `4` or `6`

Comment: `grep -P` (for perl regexen?) is a GNUism unsupported by many grep implementations. `grep -E` is more portable.